# Is there any free ldap server with data?

Tags: ldap

I need to test an application which uses LDAP for authentication, but still I don't have access to the server I have to use, but I need to test my application.

Does somebody know if is there any LDAP server with data that i can use for access??

Comment: FYI I found this https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-test-openldap to test with my software...

Comment: The same https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-image-ldapexample, just using the official docker ldap image and supporting different types and ldif autoimport. TLS/SSL included (also with auto-generation)

Answer (score 93):

Here you go: [Online LDAP Test Server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

It's free, contains data, browsable.
Make sure you use LDAP v3 when trying to bind.

Example of using from command line:

```
ldapsearch -W -h ldap.forumsys.com -D "uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com"
```

Password: **password**

Returns:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

...

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 16
# numEntries: 15
```

Comment: The forumsys server is currently available. I just connected with the above example command, and got the expected result. (I had previously used ldap.testathon.net, but that went away sometime in the past few years.)

Comment: by the way, still unavailable. try ldap://ipa.demo1.freeipa.org

Answer (score 6):

If you use the UnboundID [LDAP SDK](https://ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java/), you can stand up an in-memory LDAP server to use for testing. The API to deploy an in-memory server is included in the API. The standard edition is free, and the source code is included. I've included an example in [this blog entry](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/in-memory-directory-server/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a unix-like OS, I wrote a simple server in Java, that uses the Apache Directory Studio SDK to serve LDAP:

https://github.com/intelie/dummyldap

Comment: http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Public%20LDAP%20Servers

Answer (score -2):

ldap://directory.verisign.com is available according to one of Terry's blogs.

Comment: As far as I know, just the root DSE can be retrieved from directory.verisign.com, and the namingContexts are not visible.